# How to work with pointer structs in functions?

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>

struct bilhete{
    int horarioEntrada;
    int horarioSaida;
    int preco;
    int minEntrada;
    int minSaida;
    int horaSaida;
    int horaEntrada;
};

void extrairHoraMin(struct bilhete *a){ ///////////HERE
    a.minEntrada = a.horarioEntrada%100;
    a.horaEntrada = a.horarioEntrada/100;
    a.minSaida = a.horarioSaida%100;
    a.horaSaida = a.horarioSaida/100;
}

int obterIntervalo(struct bilhete a){
    int b = a.horaEntrada*60+a.minEntrada;
    int c = a.horaSaida*60+a.minSaida;
    return c-b;
}

int obterValorEstacionamento(int a){
    if(a<=15){return 0;}
    else if(a>15&&a<=60){return a*30;}
    else if(a>60&&a<=120){return 60*30+(a-60)*20;}
    else {return 60*30+60*20+(a-120)*10;}
}

int main()
{
    struct bilhete bilhetes[100];
    int contaCentavos, intervalo, receita=0;
    int contadorCarros=0, i, total=0;

    scanf("%d", &bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioEntrada);
    while (bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioEntrada>=0)
    {
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioSaida);
        }
        while(bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioSaida < bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioEntrada);

        extrairHoraMin(&bilhetes[contadorCarros]);  ///////////AND HERE TOO
        intervalo = obterIntervalo(bilhetes[contadorCarros]);
        contaCentavos = obterValorEstacionamento(intervalo);
        bilhetes[contadorCarros].preco = contaCentavos;
        printf("Entrada\n%02d:%02d\nSaida\n%02d:%02d\nDuracao(min)\n%d\nPreco(centavos)\n%d\n",bilhetes[contadorCarros].horaEntrada, bilhetes[contadorCarros].minEntrada, bilhetes[contadorCarros].horaSaida, bilhetes[contadorCarros].minSaida,intervalo, bilhetes[contadorCarros].preco);
        total += contaCentavos;
        contadorCarros++;
        scanf("%d", &bilhetes[contadorCarros].horarioEntrada);
    }

    printf("Faturamento total (centavos)\n%d\n", total);

    int inicioIntervalo, finalIntervalo;
    scanf("%d", &inicioIntervalo);
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &finalIntervalo);
    }
    while (finalIntervalo  < inicioIntervalo);

    for (i = 0; i < contadorCarros ; i++)
    {
        if (bilhetes[i].horarioSaida>inicioIntervalo && bilhetes[i].horarioSaida< finalIntervalo)
        {
            receita += bilhetes[i].preco;
        }
    }

    printf("\nFaturamento no periodo (centavos)\n%d\n", receita);

    return 0;
}
```

I marked the relevant parts of the question with "/////////HERE".

I need to make the function extrairHoraMin() recieve a pointer to a struct and allow me to work with the elements of the struct in question and attribute values to other variables of the struct.

It's required to not change the main() function, so how can I work with the variables of this especific struct only by changing the code on extrairHoraMin()?

Comment: Try it with a->something = somethingElse instead of a.something = somethingElse ? I'm not really sure if I understood your question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access struct field using pointer use -> operator:

```
void extrairHoraMin(struct bilhete *a){ ///////////HERE
    a->minEntrada = a->horarioEntrada%100;
    a->horaEntrada = a->horarioEntrada/100;
    a->minSaida = a->horarioSaida%100;
    a->horaSaida = a->horarioSaida/100;
}
```

Compiler should give you warning aka:

```
t.c:14:6: error: member reference type 'struct bilhete *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
    a.minEntrada = a.horarioEntrada%100;
```

Answer (score 1):

In c, when you have a pointer to a struct, to access the fields you need to use the `->` operator.

```
void extrairHoraMin(struct bilhete *a){ ///////////HERE
    a.minEntrada = a->horarioEntrada%100;
    a.horaEntrada = a->horarioEntrada/100;
    a.minSaida = a->horarioSaida%100;
    a.horaSaida = a->horarioSaida/100;
}
```

I am not really familiar with the language your variables and functions are in. But here's a full working example in English, this should demonstrate the concepts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A {
  int b;
  int c;
};
void printer(struct A* a_struct){
  printf("%d %d\n", a_struct->b, a_struct->c);
}

int main(void) {
  struct A arr[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr[i].b = i;
    arr[i].c = i;
  }
  printer(&arr[3]);
  return 0;
}
```